# Where do Green Arrow and Hawkeye get their arrows?

Tags: marvel, comics, dc, green-arrow, hawkeye

Green Arrow and Hawkeye have some pretty [awesome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick_arrows#Hawkeye.27s_trick_arrows) [arrows](http://greenarrow.wikia.com/wiki/Trick_Arrows). The Green Arrow wikia goes some way to explaining these:

> Since that time, Ollie has used his wealth and resources to fashion specialty arrows suitable for all occasions.

But it's pretty vague. Do they have a stash somewhere? Are they third party made, i.e. is there a 'trick arrow factory' somewhere?

Comment: SHEILD can obviously handle (through whatever logistics train provides their other specialty equipment) Hawkeye's arrows.  I don't know what Green Arrow did, pre-JLA, but the same argument could apply after he joins the League.  Even if it doesn't, DC has plenty of big companies that make superhero gear on the down-low (Ted Kord's, Wayne's, Luthor's, etc) so no reason GA's can't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Marvel described Hawkeye's arrows in their Hawkeye entry of the Marvel's Handbook of the Marvel Universe:**

### **Hawkeye**

**Strength level:** Hawkeye possesses the normal human strength of a man of his age, height, and build, who engages in intensive regular exercise.

**Known Superhuman Powers:** None.

**Abilities:** Hawkeye has trained himself to become an expert archer with near-perfect accuracy. He practices a minimum of two hours per day to keep his skills honed. He has also had extensive training as an aerialist and acrobat, and personal tutoring by Captain America in hand-to-hand combat. Hawkeye possesses vary keen eyesight and exceptional reflexes. Hawkeye is 80% deaf in both ears, due to an incident, and wears specially-designed miniature hearing aids.

**Weapons:** Hawkeye wields a number of custom-made bows, and carries a quiver containing various gadget-laden "trick" arrows.

[image: Hawkeye's technological arrowheads designed by Anthony Stark]

*Hawkeye's technological arrowheads designed by Anthony Stark*

**Hawkeye uses a wide variety of arrows, many of which are custom-built with devices to enhance their effectiveness in crimefighting.** Hawkeye's quiver has the capacity to carry 36 arrows. Twelve of the 36 arrows have standard target-point arrowheads, six have 3-bladed broadheads, and the remaining eighteen have various custom tips. Hawkeye has recently developed a modular arrowhead system whereby certain custom arrowheads can be attached to the shafts of any standard target-point arrow to convert them for special use. These arrowheads are stored in compartments on his tunic-belts.

**Although some of Hawkeye's more technological custom arrows were designed and built by Anthony Stark. Hawkeye himself designed the majority of his custom arrows.** To aid Hawkeye in locating the appropriate arrow with speed and accuracy, he has not only arranged the arrows in his quiver in a set pattern, he has also notch-coded the hock of each arrow so he can tell by touch which arrow he is drawing. Hawkeye is constantly modifying his arsenal of arrows.

#### Green Arrow

**Strength level:** Green Arrow possesses the normal human strength of a man of his age, height, and build, who engages in intensive regular exercise.

**Known Superhuman Powers:** None.

**Abilities:** Green Arrow is arguably one of the finest archers on the DC Earth. He is also an Olympic level gymnast and a world class martial artist. He is able to fire 29 arrows, accurately, in a single minute. To maintain his level of fitness, he trains constantly to keep up his speed, his fighting skills and his accuracy. He is also an accomplished swordsman.

**Weapons:** Green Arrow uses a variety of bows including composite and longbows. He was once a proponent of trick arrows but nowadays prefers to use normal arrows with pinpoint accuracy.

[image]

**In most of the DC continuities, Green Arrow designed his own arrow loads during his long history as DC's preeminent archer.** In the early days when he owned his own company and strongly resembled Batman, he used his vast fortune to create the specialized non-lethal arrowheads he and his sidekick Speedy/Arsenal used.

- Given his wealth at the time, he was probably able to buy the components the same way Batman did, through shell companies and putting them together himself.
- Once he became a member of the Justice League, his options grew and he was able to utilize League resources to advance his arsenal and increase their capabilities.
- For a time, he gave up using specialized arrowheads and returned to common arrows. Ollie's son Conner, (from the previous DC continuity) never appreciated his father's trick arrows and only used normal arrows except for a brief stint in the Justice League.
- In the modern DC continuity, he prefers to use normal arrows but will break out a trick arrow if the situation calls for it.

Answer (score 0):

I read that Hawkeye's recurve bow has an unbelievably high draw weight of 250 lbs. (that's awful heavy as the best hunting recurves out there top off at 65 lbs. draw) considering that, most if not all the arrow shafts commercially available would not be able to stand the force of launch from that bow as they could break apart, they would have to be specially produced for him. Maybe a Stark 3-D printer (or something like what Stark uses for building lots of Iron Man suits) for making them? The same could be said of making Green Arrow's shafts and arrow components as well.

Comment: But how would they get their arrows before the invention of the 3D printer?

Comment: The Marvel and DC Universe seems to be somehow technologically more advanced than in real life, in the 1980's there was a comic called Marvel Universe that described something like 3-D printing in making Iron Man's suit (or part of it) which is weird because that was decades before 3-D printing as we know it came to be. Also, the result of mixing fictional Vibranium and steel to make Captain America's shield (in the same 80's comic) describes well what "meta-materials" we are just making now like infusing Graphene to metals and plastics to make super-strong objects.

Comment: It's just a suggestion considering that DC and Marvel are always (again and again) rebooting their universes to catch up with the times, it may be more realistic that the comics provide their characters with a more realistic source of advanced weapons on demand. Most likely, before that they would have spent hours assembling the arrows as some archers do (fletching, adding inserts, points, nocks and stuff), now that's real patience and dedication.

Answer (score 0):

Many archers I know (I'm a recreational archer myself) do make their own arrows, actually assembling them, buying bare shafts and adding the components by hand or with devices like fletching jigs. You can make several dozen in less than a day and after the glues have cured, you can use them. The trick heads, I just have to assume that these characters are really good at inventing amazing stuff like Peter Parker making those web shooters but that's part of what makes these comics fun.

Comment: This is very interesting! Do we know if this is how Hawkeye and Green Arrow get their arrows, though?